# Issues while setting up Eclipse with Flex SDK

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, sdk, eclipse-plugin, flex4.5

I am following this post (http://www.seanhsmith.com/2010/03/29/flex-for-free-setting-up-the-flex-4-sdk-with-eclipse-ide/) for setting up of Eclipse with Flex. Am using Flex 4.6 SDK and Eclipse IDE 4.3.
As per the instructions in the post, when I am putting the code snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

</s:Application>
```

in the application.mxml file, the editor is unable to recognise xml, flex and mx. Eventually, the compilation is failing. Probable issues might be?

Comment: The link you have provided goes to a 404 error; so I'm not sure which instructions you are following.  If you want an Eclipse based IDE for Flex applications; I strongly recommend getting Flash Builder.

Comment: @Reboog711 Please check this now: http://www.seanhsmith.com/2010/03/29/flex-for-free-setting-up-the-flex-4-sdk-with-eclipse-ide/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an open source project which does this already:

- [Flash Builder 4 Linux](http://code.google.com/p/fb4linux/)
- [Install Guide for Flash Builder 4 Linux](https://code.google.com/p/fb4linux/wiki/HowToInstall)
- [Design View Port](http://sourceforge.net/projects/designview/)